# Query MongoDB by _id with RazorSQL

Tags: mongodb, razorsql

I'm trying to query a document by id from a mongodb with razorsql. I enter the following query into the query editor:

```
"phonebook-repository-dev".phonebookEntry.findOne({_id: "qG1B_WgEppRgL0kV4c9dsw"})
```

When running the query, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: JSON Parsing error: invalid ObjectId [qG1B_WgEppRgL0kV4c9dsw]

Query
= "phonebook-repository-dev".phonebookEntry.findOne({_id:
"qG1B_WgEppRgL0kV4c9dsw"})
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I never used RazorSQL but a search by ObjectId works as follows:

```
db.your_collection.findOne({"_id":ObjectId("your_object_id_here")})

Query = "phonebook-repository-dev".phonebookEntry.findOne({_id:ObjectId(
"qG1B_WgEppRgL0kV4c9dsw")})
```

Try to create an ObjectId and see if it works.

Comment: We don't use ObjectIds, but strings in our _id field. The query works as expected on the commandline.